# One field primary key in multiple tables

Tags: primary-key, ms-access-2010

My database in Access has a table named Program and its primary key is Program ID. I have some other tables which have additional information relating to the Programs in the Program table. Each of these tables has the field Program ID in them. For example: I have a table named [Additional topics] . The [Additional topics] table has multiple value fields that stores information about the topics and sub topics associated with the Programs. The Program ID field joins the Program table with the [Additional topics]. The Program ID in the [Additional topics] table has no duplicates (as I have the other fields as multiple value fields). So, My question is, should I make Program ID as a Primary key to the [Additional topics] table or should I create a separate ID field for it?
Please help
Thank You

Comment: so one program has only one additional topic?

Comment: @ mosaad. NO, one Program may have one or more additional topics. The [Additional topics] has 3 fields in total Program ID, topics, sub-topics. The topics and sub-topics fields are drop down lists that allow multiple values to be selected. So each Program ID in the [Additional topics] table ends up having one record only. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer no

If the ProgarmID only appears once in the additional topics table this would be a 1 to 1 relationship and you should ask yourself do you need the separate table or could you add the fields to the Program table.

The only reason I can think to use foreign key (the) in as a primary key would be as part of a primary key where the primary key is composed of two foreign keys.

Comment: Does that mean, Its better if I add the fields in the additional topics table into the program table and delete the additional topics table.

Answer (score 0):

Since a program can have one or more Additional topics then it is not possible that the program ID is unique for additional topics and so you must use another ID and program ID will just be a foreign key

Comment: Ok. I have another doubt, its a little out of topic for this question though. I am migrating the access tables to sql server 2008. So, is it a good idea to have multi-valued fields in sql server? Or should I get rid of all the multi-valued fields in access before I migrate to sql server.

Comment: i dont hv much experience with multi-valued fields but according to http://dbaspot.com/sqlserver-server/457974-multi-valued-fields-does-ss8-support.html its not a good idea to use them